# Phone not sleeping using WakefulIntentService *alarm* the cause

Tags: android, android-wake-lock

I've an app that runs as a service using an alarm manager and an IntentService with a wakelock that's acquired and released as the service starts and ends.

I've been looking at the dumps of the battery stats and see my wakeful services listed look to be ok:

```
Wake lock u0a121 MyAppWakeLock: 9ms (1 times) realtime
```

But for some reason I'm also seeing:

```
All partial wake locks:
Wake lock u0a121 *alarm*: 25s 817ms (0 times) realtime
```

that's also associated with my process.

Sometimes the *alarm* row doesn't regsiter with hardly any time and then the CPU will sleep and the PowerManagerService.Wakelocks seem to be ok and tie up with the CPU sleep, but when it does it prevents any sleeping.

I can track in logs that the acquire and release are firing for the wakelock ok.

Does anyone know what's meant by * alarm* in this situation and why it stops the device sleeping.

I've tried playing around with Marks WakefulIntentService to add in a timeout on the aquire and that hasn't helped.

Sometime the app can run for hours fine (doing repeated 15 minute wake) and then suddenly I start seeing the * alarm* again.

Comment: What is `MyAppWakeLock` ? "...IntentService ..." " ...my wakeful services ..." - are your services WakefulIS ?

Comment: "All partial wake locks:" is printed by whom ? Try grepping the source for "*alarm*":  http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/search?q=%22*alarm*%22&project=frameworks - which android version ? See also http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/AlarmManagerService.java (those are jelly bean sources)

Comment: MyAppWakeLock is coming from my IntentService where it acquires a wakelock and passes it a tag. "all partial wake locks" is coming from "adb shell dumpsys batterystats"

Comment: MyAppWakeLock is the class or the TAG ? What do you mean by "my wakeful services" ?

Comment: Grep adb's source - and post the link back here out of curiosity - the site I chose above was pretty much at random